# Need unique field to identify using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to find the the unique field to identify the search box and enter text in it.

```
   <style type="text/css">
</head>
<body style="min-height: 81px;">
<div class="shared-page" data-cid="view221" data-view="views/shared/Page" data-render-time="0.02">
<a class="navSkip" tabindex="1" href="#navSkip">Screen reader users, click here to skip the navigation bar</a>
<header role="banner">
<a id="navSkip"></a>
<div class="main-section-body" role="main">
<div class="timeline" data-cid="view4947" data-view="views/timeline/Master" data-render-time="0.107">
<div class="section-padded section-header">
<div class="timeline-title" data-cid="view5085" data-view="views/timeline/Title" data-render-time="0.001">
<div class="search-bar-wrapper shared-searchbar" data-cid="view4948" data-view="views/shared/searchbar/Master" data-render-time="0.104">
<form class="search-form" action="" method="get">
<table class="search-bar search-bar-primary">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="search-input" width="100%">
<div id="search" class="shared-searchbar-input" data-cid="view4949" data-view="views/shared/searchbar/Input" data-render-time="0.002">
<div class="search-field-background"> </div>
<div class="search-field-wrapper">
<label class="placeholder-text" for="397271.5897375417" style="display: block;">enter search here...</label>
<textarea id="397271.5897375417" class="search-field" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" name="q" rows="1"></textarea>
```

**textarea** is the field related to the search box. I tried using class, name but it says unable to locate element, the numeric id too is dynamic. Please let me know what to use in this case.

Comment: Is it in bold font? Please, correct your question.

Comment: Put the code how you used class to identify.

Comment: Is there multiple similar textarea present on that page?

Comment: ive updated the whole body of the code @Nadun

Comment: If none of the answers below help you, can post a link to a live page that shows this?

Comment: its an internal server page not accesible outside :(

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@class='search-field']"));
```

Or

```
driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
```

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//textarea[@class='search-field']"}

Comment: Add explicit wait and try. Most probably element not loading with the page load.

Comment: ive added this sleep "Thread.sleep(1000); ". Still the same. @Nadun

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to find this element by class name

in ruby:
`driver.find_element(:class, "search-field")`

or in java:
`driver.findElement(By.className("search-field"));`

Comment: same prob- unable to locate element "search-field"

Answer (score 0):

Following xpath should work:

```
//div[@id='search']//textarea[@class='search-field']
```

Comment: same prob. it says "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//textarea[@class='search-field']"}
"

Comment: Did you used `By.xpath("//div[@id='search']//textarea[@class='search-field']")`? As the error message says, it seems like `By.xpath("//textarea[@class='search-field']")` have been used.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='search']//textarea[@class='search-field']"}
@mfsi

Comment: Can you print this: `System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='search']//textarea[@class='search-field‌​']")).size())` and paste the output here?

Comment: i tried this...it doesnt prinft anythng in the console

Answer (score 0):

If the `<textarea>` is only one, you can search with

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("textarea"));
```

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"textarea"}

Comment: Is this under any frames? `<iframe>`

Comment: i don think so. updated the code with the entire body

Comment: Can you provide the URL? if possible